# iOS App Store Receipt, file does not exist

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I'm implementing an auto freemium upgrade for an existing iPhone application. The app used to be paid, and now the app will become free with a paid iAP upgrade to support certain premium features.

I would like to automatically upgrade the existing users that have paid for the app before I made it free.

For this, I'm calling the iOS7 "appStoreReceiptURL" method on [NSBundle mainBundle]. This always returns a file URL, however, when running this through the debugger/xcode and trying to read/parse the data from the receipt file, the actual file doesn't exist.

From what I could find, an app receipt (not iAP, just the mainBundle app receipt) should apparently always exist for an iOS7 app. However, there are times when it doesn't exist in a development environment.

Could anyone confirm this? Or do I actually still need to use SKReceiptRefreshRequest to refresh the receipt?

Answer (score 0):

Since you installed the app via Xcode and not from the Store it contains no receipt. You can start a SKReceiptRefreshRequest in order to get a sandbox receipt you can use for testing.

Also be aware that you need to log out of the App Store and use a test user account (created in iTunes Connect) when prompted to log in after you started the request to make it work.

I also read that you might be able to get a real receipt if you install the app (with Xcode) "over" a version you downloaded from the Store, but I haven't tested that yet.